# X Path into NVP XML

Tags: xpath

Can someone please tell me the xpath to select the value for the "FPPRNO" pair in the following doc - I need to select "ABC123":

```
<lcc:Request Version="1" xmlns:lcc="http://LCC.Integration.Corporate.Schemas.MvcForms.MvcFormsRequestOrResponse">
         <lcc:FormType>HMORenewal</lcc:FormType>
         <lcc:Data>
            <lcc:Pair>
               <lcc:Name>LicenseRefNo</lcc:Name>
               <lcc:Value>16/XXX31/HMO</lcc:Value>
            </lcc:Pair>
            <lcc:Pair>
               <lcc:Name>FPPRNO</lcc:Name>
               <lcc:Value>ABC123</lcc:Value>
            </lcc:Pair>
                                <lcc:Pair>
               <lcc:Name>ApplyAccreditationDiscount</lcc:Name>
               <lcc:Value>False</lcc:Value>
            </lcc:Pair>
                                <lcc:Pair>
               <lcc:Name>NumberOfTenants</lcc:Name>
               <lcc:Value>5</lcc:Value>
            </lcc:Pair>
         </lcc:Data>
      </lcc:Request>
```

Comment: What about `//lcc:Pair[lcc:Name = "FPPRNO"]/lcc:Value/text()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
//*[lcc:Name = 'FPPRNO']/lcc:Value/text()
```